# powershell or bat - counting files in all directories and subdirec

Tags: active-directory, command-line-interface, powershell, count

we have a hardrive with hundreds of thousands of files

i need to figure out how many of every file extension we have

how can i do this with windowspowershell or command prompt or what ever else is available??

i need it to go through every directory. this lawyers at my company need this. it can be a total for the entire hardrive it does not have to be broken down by directory

example:

```
1232 JPEG
11 exe
45 bat
2342 avi
532 doc
```

Comment: If you want a non-CLI option, this is a very nice tool: http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/

Comment: You know, of course, that the extension is only a hint.  I can name my files any way I like and they will be usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dir -recurse | group-object Extension -noelement

Comment: I just tried this out. Nice answer!

Comment: Powershell FTW! Can't be more direct than that.

Comment: group-object is an awesome cmdlet.  it's like "Group by" in SQL except that you don't lose the details (unless you want to, as in this case with -noelement).  That is, you can loop through the base objects in each group.

Comment: It'd be even more awesome if it supported agrregation without needing to go through `group|foreach{$_.group|foreach{$_|Add-member ...}}`

Comment: @Joey...I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: mike i don't know if you are still active here but i asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614614/displaying-frequency-distribution-of-all-files-recursively-that-were-modified-in

Answer (score 2):

Just because I can: A quick and dirty `cmd` solution that's not much longer than the PowerShell one:

```
(for /r %f in (*) do @(set /a EXT:%~xf+=1 >nul 2>&1))&set EXT:
```

Comment: this is freakin awesome how did u learn to do this?

Comment: @I__: I have fun solving complex tasks in archaic or limited languages. Note though that this won't work for two directory trees within the same `cmd` session since it's all just environment variables I don't reset after use.